# Exclude Some files and folder from CI/CD devops pipeline building Artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am new in Azure DevOps. I have configured a pipeline for Continuously Deploying application on IIS Server. Right now its working fine but my issue is how can i Skip/Exclude some files and folders (Configurations files, Documents folders etc.) from Publishing Artifacts and Deploying the application on IIS Server.
I did some R&D internet on it a find a solution in shape of .artifactignore file. But this is not working OR maybe i am doing wrong. I did as explained [here](https://www.jfe.cloud/control-pipeline-artifacts-with-artifactignore-file/).
Is there any other ways or any one can explain this to me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same need and have not found a way to exclude or delete files or folders either. This seems like a really obvious, normal thing to do, so I can't believe there isn't a built-in option or extremely simple task to do this. I took a look at the built-in "Delete files" task, but this appears to be related ONLY to the Agent Working folders and not the IIS deployment folders, so it's utterly useless.